# Remove optional ubuntu packages for speeding up release-upgrade

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, package-management, do-release-upgrade, download-speed

I have to update ubuntu 13 to ubuntu 14. When I issued `release-upgrade` it is showing that about 700 MB data is to be downloaded from internet. I have slow internet connection now. So it will take hours to complete. I believe if I remove some optional packages then it will ignore their updates. Hence I can reduce the amount of data downloaded from internet. How can I do it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "optional" will have specific meaning for you and for others. So in general to make the download size smaller, you could follow these steps:

1) I noticed that the maximum space is occupied by the "debug" symbol packages. They are used to help developers find out crash points easily.

You can uninstall these safely without any risks. They usually have a "-dbg" at the end of their name, e.g., python2.7 package has a corresponding debug symbol package "python2.7-dbg"

This process of selecting dbg packages should be done manually by you and it will save the maximum space.

2) Remove any unwanted softwares that you don't use. We usually have multiple browsers, multimedia apps etc. Go the "1 app per utility" way to reduce space.